# Log file for Databricks python notebook execution

Tags: python-3.x, logging, databricks

I am using databricks and writing my code in python notebook. Recently we deployed it in prod. However sometimes the notebook is getting failed.

I am looking for notebook command execution log file however there is no option to generate the log file in databricks.

I want to store log files in DBFS with timestamp so i can refer these log files if it fails.

Is there anyway we can achieve this? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to do this. You would utilize the Databricks API. This is taken from their [website](https://docs.databricks.com/api/latest/examples.html#cluster-log-delivery-examples).

Create a cluster with logs delivered to a DBFS location
The following cURL command creates a cluster named “cluster_log_dbfs” and requests Databricks to sends its logs to dbfs:/logs with the cluster ID as the path prefix.

```
curl -n -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d @- https://<databricks-
instance>/api/2.0/clusters/create <<JSON
    {
      "cluster_name": "cluster_log_dbfs",
      "spark_version": "5.2.x-scala2.11",
      "node_type_id": "i3.xlarge",
      "num_workers": 1,
      "cluster_log_conf": {
        "dbfs": {
          "destination": "dbfs:/logs"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you gold, i will try with this solution. I am not sure whether it gives us notebook commands execution output, that's what i am expecting. I hope this will give what i am looking for.

Comment: this is giving whole cluster log output which is almost not understandable and actually i am looking for only notebook execution output.